# How to declare a function J as a function of q?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

How can you write the following in Mathematica?

```
J[x,t]=q[x,t]*D[q[x,t],x]
```

I want to use this identity in another equation.

Comment: I think reading some tutorials would be a [good start](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to define such a function:

```
J[x_, q_] := q*D[q, x]
```

so, for example,

```
J[x, q[x, t]]
```

will give

```
q[x, t] * D[q[x, t], x]
```